# I get this error : If using all scalar values must pass index . I'm writing a basic jason dataframe and it shows this error

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

This is my code:

```
data ='{"name": " sani", "address": " Czech", "Age": "10", "Gender": "Female"}'
pd.read_json(data) ( I cannot execute this line, it shows that error)
```

i tried adding Index= 0 and it didn't work as well

Comment: what was the error you got? what did you expect to happen instead? why are you trying to load that data into a pandas dataframe?

Comment: Because I’m using Pandas library in Jupyter notebook so in order to change the json data into a data frame I use the above code

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just passing the values as just plain strings, use lists instead.

Here is your example fixed:

```
import pandas as pd
data ='{"name": [" sani"], "address": [" Czech"], "Age": ["10"], "Gender": ["Female"]}'

pd.read_json(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

because your data's type is **string** not **dictionary**. First convert string to dictionary:

```
import json
data ='{"name": " sani", "address": " Czech", "Age": "10", "Gender": "Female"}'
data=json.loads(data)
```

then use json_normalize for convert to dataframe:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data)
```

full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

data ='{"name": " sani", "address": " Czech", "Age": "10", "Gender": "Female"}'
data=json.loads(data)
df=pd.json_normalize(data)

print(df)
'''
    name    address Age Gender
0    sani    Czech  10  Female

'''
```